# "Фигура в венце на голове" – можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

*Под стружкой стояла статуя: мраморная **фигура юноши в оливковом венце на голове.***
[**Тесс Герритсен, Кто украл мое сердце**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=10647&p=52)

Не могу понять (в чем проблема?), но ощущаю какой-то диссонанс между словами.
Грамотно ли так говорить: *фигура в венце на голове?*
Если есть неточность, то как должно быть правильно?

**Дополнение** (если ссылка не открывается):
Второе помещение тоже было заставлено ящиками с логотипом «Кэрнкросс». Однако здесь стояли ящики разных размеров. Некоторые были такие большие, что в них свободно помещался стоящий человек.
Клеа ломом отжала крышку, запустила внутрь руки. Руки сразу утонули в россыпи стружки. Под стружкой она нащупала что-то твердое и потянула это твердое вверх. Вскоре в лучах искусственного света блеснул мрамор…
Под стружкой стояла статуя: мраморная фигура юноши в оливковом венце на голове.
От волнения у Клеа задрожали руки. Она выхватила из рюкзака фотоаппарат и начала поспешно фотографировать. Сняв статую со всех сторон, она закрыла крышку ящика и вскрыла соседний.

Comment: И ещё одна несуразность: фигура мраморная, а венец оливковый. Мраморной должна быть статуя.

Comment: Несуразностей и ляпов в этой разрекламированной книге  – предостаточно: хватит не на один вопрос.

Comment: Мраморное с оливковым не конфликтует: натура для мраморной фигуры - юноша в оливковом венце (_в белом венчике из роз _; в очках и т. п.); "голова", конечно, лишняя (иначе - "с венцом" на голове). Но вот загадка: _под стружкой_ статуя могла только **скрываться** - откуда подробности о ней?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Доступ к ресурсу по вашей ссылке заблокирован на территории РФ. Лучше бы как-нибудь без этого, имхо.

Comment: А у меня ссылка спокойно открывается. Vabandage. Sorry. Извините. Сейчас изображу - как дополнение к вопросу.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Так Вам указали - на территории РФ.В Эстонии - можно.

Comment: Не поняла: ЧТО - можно?

Answer (score 4):

***Под стружкой стояла статуя: мраморная фигура юноши в оливковом венце.***

Слово ВЕНЕЦ - (устар.) - то же, что ВЕНОК - здесь вполне можно употребить. Ср.: *ВЕНЕЦ терновый.* Нужно только убрать избыточное "на голове" (ВЕНЕЦ в значении НИМБ, КОРОНА может быть только на голове).

***Под стружкой стояла статуя: мраморная фигура юноши с оливковым венком на голове.***

В этом примере, на мой взгляд,  выражение "с венком на голове" звучит нормально, ибо венок, являясь головным убором, тем не менее может быть и в руке, и на шее, и где угодно: "Венки оставляли на деревьях и чердаках от молний, клали под первый сноп для увеличения следующего урожая, подкладывали в гнездо наседки, в колыбель новорожденного, прятали под одежду от ведьм, вешали в полях и огородах. Девушки умывались водой с мокрого венка для красоты и здоровья...Венок – из искусственных цветов, ниток – нередко надевали на шляпу жениху, оберегая его от сглаза".[Венок как древний славянский оберег](https://sites.google.com/site/moarossia10/prazdniki-i-obycai-rusi/russkie-oberegi/venok-kak-drevnij-slavanskij-obereg)

Comment: Не-а, это не то значение. Здесь - венец. Как символ. Оливковый - только венец, венок - это только сразу другое наполнение. Олимпийское...

Answer (score 3):

**ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ**

**1) Что обсуждаем?**

Наверное, проблему перевода. Тесс Герритсен, американская писательница-прозаик китайского происхождения, создавшая серию бестселлеров в жанрах медицинского и романтического триллера.

**2) Полный текст:**

"Второе помещение тоже было заставлено ящиками с логотипом «Кэрнкросс». Однако здесь стояли ящики разных размеров. Некоторые были такие большие, что в них свободно помещался стоящий человек.

Клеа ломом отжала крышку, запустила внутрь руки. Руки сразу утонули в россыпи стружки. Под стружкой она нащупала что-то твердое и потянула это твердое вверх. Вскоре в лучах искусственного света блеснул мрамор…

**Под стружкой стояла статуя: мраморная фигура юноши в оливковом венце на голове.**

3) Наверное, английский текст выглядел так: **the figure of the man in the olive crown on his head.**

Перевод дословный, но по-русски так не говорят. Нужен литературный перевод, вот над ним мы и работаем, предлагаем версии.

Например: a wreath - **венок, гирлянда, венец, веночек**. Что выбрать?

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

**Под стружкой стояла статуя: мраморная фигура юноши в оливковом венке.**

1) **Неправильно**: в венке на голове (мы же не говорим "в шапке на голове").

2) Венец – многозначное слово, но в качестве венка – **это обычно символ страданий, мученичества,** поэтому такой венок/венец чаще бывает **терновым**.

**Для справок**: Наградой в Олимпии был только оливковый венок, а в Дельфах — лавровый. [М. Л. Гаспаров. Занимательная Греция (1998)]

3) Соответственно, "фигура юноши с венцом на голове" **тоже не лучший вариант**.

Comment: Соответственно *чему* не лучший?

Comment: Соответственно вышесказанному. Меня как-то пугает эта фигура юноши  с венцом на голове.

Comment: Там венец, не венок.

Comment: Венец - в переводе, а не "там". И обсуждается перевод, не слишком удачный. И предлагаются и обсуждаются варианты перевода. И всем это понятно, кроме одного лица, у которого "там венец, не венок". А там - это где? Ну, где-то там...

Answer (score 2):

Фигура в венце? Девушка в венке на голове. Ужас какой... С венком на голове! Соответственно, в вашем случае – "фигура юноши с венцом на голове".

Comment: Девушки с веслом стоят обычно, а в стружке и венке — юноша.

Answer (score 1):

Если фигура именно **стояла** под стружкой, то возникает фантастическая картина: стоит ящик высотой около двух метров. Женщина (не супервумен) тянет тяжелую мраморную статую вверх и извлекает ее целиком, так что может сфотографировать ее со всех сторон, а затем возвращает статую в ящик. В то же время извлеченная статуя каким-то образом оставалась под стружкой. Но это не помешало сфотографировать ее со всех сторон. Ляп на ляпе.

А юноша мог бы быть "увенчан оливковым венком" или просто "с оливковым венком на голове". По-моему, было бы преувеличением считать, что едва обаружив статую какого-то юноши, героиня тут же определила, что у него на голове не просто венок, а некий символ - "венец".